# How to ask about biological gender

Tags: forms, gender

When asking the question about gender we need to take into account the person's identifying gender but still need to know their biological gender. I would like to understand the best combination of questions to ask this.

The current system is just "Male" / "Female" and we don't the people who just use that have extra to click.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQFQKE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I was thinking of changing this first to "biological gender" and adding a third option to allow the user to show that their identifying gender is different.

Or alternatively a second question is "This your identifying gender" but then everybody would have to answer it.

What is an ideal sequence of question and answers to determine both biological gender and identifying gender?

Also considering mobile vs desktop.

Comment: In many cases, gender really doesn't need to be known. Do you have a legitimate reason to ask that question?

Comment: Yes definitely needed, otherwise we would not ask. aside from privacy less things to fill in gives a better experience.

Comment: Why is this relevant? Assuming it is, knowing a little more might help when and how to ask this (perhaps this screen isn't the *best* choice...

Comment: The third phrase of the question is missing some verbs

Comment: Change the label from "Gender" to "Sex" and all your problems go away.

Comment: Gender and Sex are different things. 'Biological Gender' is not really a meaningful term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_and_gender_distinction

Comment: What about intersex people without assigned sex?

Answer (score 9):

Since the biological sex and the identifying gender will be the same in most cases, you should avoid forcing users to explicitly select both.

You could let all the users select their biological sex, and let them specify a different identifying gender only if they click on a link that says something like *"My identifying gender is different"*.
Most people won't need to be prompted with a second gender select form, and they won't mind not having to click on that link.

[image: Form demo]

Keep in mind that this is a really sensitive data; so you should comply with many strict privacy regulations.

Comment: Beware, for "Identifying gender" 'Male' and 'Female' may not be enough. Facebook has identified around 50 different identifying options for gender: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/facebook/10637968/Facebook-sex-changes-which-one-of-50-genders-are-you.html

Comment: See also: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/85479/using-genders-in-physiologically-oriented-ucd for a discussion of when to use gender identity and when to use gender assigned at birth