# Is it ok to give "OTHERS" as an option in gender category?

Tags: forms, data-collection, gender

Normally we have sex as:

1) male

2) female

I just added "others" option in the list.My teacher when checked the form, she was 
annoyed and suggested it should be removed.

So is it really an bad option?What is wrong with it?

Comment: Firstly, your teacher is wrong (and very likely closed minded).  Secondly, this has been dealt with in another question already: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25826/how-can-i-deal-with-diverse-gender-identities-in-user-profiles/25832#25832

Comment: It's a valid question, yes. Glad you're challenging what your teacher says. Gender is a complex issue. However it is a duplicate question so we'll link this one to that original to get you some extra info.

Comment: Gender is difficult because the traditional way of perceiving it fades into past. No reason to ask if it's right or bot, it's a cultural/social question. There is an ISO standard behind it even (you can find it following link in JohnGB's comment). Just one more thought - sometimes gender passes to another meaning, is used in another context. In one of the forms I worked on there was an issue with using gender to determine if user is a father or mother, while there should be even more options provided (adopter for example).